# Can anyone give me some sample sentences that fit each definitions of "skittish"?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I have searched for its meaning in online dictionaries, and have found about 5 meanings for the word "skittish". Those meanings are

> 1. lively or frisky in action
> 2. (Of a person) playfully frivolous or unpredictable
> 3. coy, bashful
> 4. (of an animal, especially of a horse) excitable or easily scared.
> 5. fickle or uncertain

Google translate has provided some sample sentences, but I don't know how to use it to discover what kind of context will fit well with each of these definitions, so please help me out.

Comment: Skittish: you can see example sentences here under each definition: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/skittish

Comment: Thank you. I have looked in this website already, but I still get confused.

Comment: You should make clear what you don't understand!

Comment: Like what the definition of "skittish" in each sentences should mean. I don't have problem with the fourth meaning, but 1,2,3 and 5 are quite difficult to differentiate when it is in the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the OED with many different senses, with examples dating from as early as 1402. It is believed to be of Scandinavian origin. Interestingly there are no examples more recent than the 19th century, suggesting that the word may be in less mainstream use today. I give each OED meaning below with its most recent example:

**1. Of disposition, etc.: Characterized by levity, frivolity, or excessive liveliness.**

1894   J. Knight D. Garrick iv. 68   Macklin claims to have supplied a curiously unconventional and skittish rhymed apology.

**2. 
 a. Of horses, etc.: Disposed or apt to start or be unruly without sufficient cause; given to shying or restiveness through high spirits or playfulness; unduly lively or spirited.**

1882   B. D. W. Ramsay Recoll. Mil. Serv. I. i. 8   A very skittish, and at times vicious, thoroughbred colt.

**b. Similarly of other animals.**

1837   T. Hood Ode R. Wilson 241   Exactly as a skittish Scottish bull Hunts an old woman in a scarlet cloak.

**3. Fickle, inconstant, changeable; tricky, difficult to deal with or manage.**

1872   ‘G. Eliot’ Middlemarch I. ii. xv. 252   The management and training of the most skittish or vicious diseases.

**4. Spirited, active, lively; frolicsome.**

1887   A. Jessopp Arcady v. 166   Sobriety of dress must be enforced, and skittish widows protected from their own volatile tastes.

**5. Inclined to show coyness or reserve.**

1865   T. Carlyle Hist. Friedrich II of Prussia VI. xxi. iv. 475   Kaunitz and his Empress are extremely skittish in the matter, and as if quite refuse it at first.

Comment: In English as used today?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I confess I was not aware of sense 5. But I have certainly heard people talk of something such as *there's no accounting for his/her girl-friend's/boy-friend's skittish behaviour*. When you were a teacher did you never have teenage pupils who behaved *skittishly*? Until I looked it up in the OED I had no idea it had been around so long and might have connected it to schizophrenia!

Comment: Sorry. Can you give less strange-sounding examples?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth *When he comes in drunk he behaves skittishly. Last Thursday he put the milk in the tumble dryer and the cat in the fridge. There is no telling what he will do next.*

Comment: The trouble with OED is that their historical examples tend to be unhelpful (other than to etymologists). Even if they illustrate modern usages, the words tend to be in archaic settings.

Answer (score 0):

By doing some research on my own, here's a  sentence for each one of your meanings:

1 - He'll have had such a rest that he'll be quite skittish.

2 - my skittish and immature mother

3 - Cade was trying to be accommodating, but sometimes he was as skittish about conversation as the cat was about being touched - and likely for the same reason.

4 - Are stallions always skittish like that?

5 - Any filly would be skittish about going into a stable where the ghost of another lingered

Hope that will help you figured it out